# Want to control fog setting for each individual lights sources in the Scenes for Cycles Renderer

Tags: cycles-render-engine, volumetrics

I am using Blender 3.5.1, and I am not able to find volume setting for each light.
For example I need the Fog for Lamp and for other lights I don't need,
So is there any option to turn off / on volume fog?
I am rendering the scene in Cycles.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be soon available (Blender 3.6) and it's called "Light linking".

For example here,

[image]

The green light won't affect the volume, and the red light won't affect Suzanne (directly).

This is done by defining a collection in the "Light linking" part of the lamp properties, and indicating what will be affected or not by the light:

[image]

Still experimental, but [available here](https://builder.blender.org/download/experimental/).

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up will wait for final release of 3.6.